# AngularJS: SyntaxError Occurs when requesting for a file (json content) using $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

i need to access a file using $http service. But ***iam getting below error***  in Browser console.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
    at Object.parse (native)
    at vc (http://localhost/libFile/angular.min.js:15:313)
    at $b (http://localhost/libFile/angular.min.js:81:301)
    at http://localhost/libFile/angular.min.js:82:216
    at n (http://localhost/libFile/angular.min.js:7:322)
    at ed (http://localhost/libFile/angular.min.js:82:198)
    at c (http://localhost/libFile/angular.min.js:83:382)
    at http://localhost/libFile/angular.min.js:119:302
    at m.$get.m.$eval (http://localhost/libFile/angular.min.js:134:83)
    at m.$get.m.$digest (http://localhost/libFile/angular.min.js:131:106)
```

Below is html template with Angular expressions. There is no error here

```
<html ng-app="nameApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://localhost/libFile/angular.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
  var nameApp = angular.module('nameApp',[]);
    nameApp.controller('myController' , function($scope,$http)
    {
      $http.get('http://localhost/checkangular/art_1.json').success(function(data){
          $scope.arts = data;
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myController">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="art in arts">
   {{art.movie}} - {{art.mainChar}}
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

My art_1.json file.

```
[
  {'movie' : 'i am legand','mainChar':'Will Smith'},
  {'movie' : 'Batman Begins','mainChar' : 'Christian Bale'},
  {'movie' : 'Man of Steel', 'mainChar' : 'Henry Cavill'}
];
```

i browsed for finding solution and figured that i might have missed parameters in $http service or modules i did not import. In online tutorials its like they do the same and it works for them.

i am using AngularJS v1.4.0 library
Kindly suggest me a solution here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it's invalid JSON. JSON uses `"` instead of `'`, and it doesn't end with `;`.

You can use a tool like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to verify. You could also read up on [JSON](http://www.json.org/) and its syntax. Also, just don't build JSON by hand. That's prone to a lot of errors.

Comment: it worked.in atom editor it highlighted in red when i enclosed with ' but i ignored it.. am embarrassed  right now..:)

Comment: glad you said about JsonLint